# QGIS Server WFS features are initially not displayed in project

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server

1. I created a blank new QGIS project in 3.32.
2. I added a shapefile layer with LineStrings. It is valid. The extents are correct.
3. I went Project Properties -> WFS/OAPIF and published the single layer.
4. I saved the project and added it to a FastCGI QGIS Server 3.28.
5. I add the layer via the server's WFS1/2 URL https://example.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/path/to/project.qgz

The canvas is blank.

QGIS raises a red error bar saying "Layer my_layer: Layer extent reported by the server is not correct. You may need to zoom on layer and then zoom out to see all features"

I can zoom and pan the map, the data is not appearing.

Only if I manually enable "Show Feature Count" for the layer, QGIS will count for a while and then display the layer (in the right location).

What am I missing?